# how to redirect user to logout page when token or refresh token expired using bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, navigator, refresh-token

This is my base repository where it gets the data from the bloc I want to redirect the user to a custom page like logout when the token expires or refresh token expire. I change pages, in bloc consumer or bloc listener but in this case, this  is stupid work because I should replace bloc consumer with another bloc method everywhere I request to the server

```
 @override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get(String url) async {
    // Uri newUrl = Uri.parse(baseUrl + url);
    var newUrl = baseUrl + url;
    dio.Response response;
    try {
      // x.interceptors.add(dio.InterceptorsWrapper(
      //   onError: (e, handler) {
      //     if(e.response!.statusCode == 401)
      //         redirect user to custom page
      //   },
      // ));
      response = await dio.Dio()
          .get(newUrl, options: dio.Options(headers: headersList))
          .timeout(duration);
      var result = _processResponse(response);
      if (result.runtimeType.toString().toLowerCase() == 'string') {
        return <String, String>{'key': result};
      }
      return result;
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('internetConnection');
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw ApiNotRespondingException('api not found ');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      var response = e as dio.DioError;
      print(e.toString());
      throw _handleError(response);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you have found a solution please share it

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked myself the same question and come up with this solution (maybe not the best one).

1. You need a separated bloc for containing jwt tokens;
2. Init this bloc as a singleton. I use [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) that uses [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) as a DI

```
@singleton
class TokenBloc extends Bloc<TokenEvent, TokenState> {
  final ISecureStorage secureStorage;

  TokenBloc(this.secureStorage) : super(TokenInitial()) {
    on<TokenReseted>(delete);
    on<TokenUpdated>(put);
  }

  put(event, emit) {
    emit(TokenAuthentificated(event.accessToken, event.refreshToken));
    secureStorage.write('accessToken', event.accessToken);
    secureStorage.write('refreshToken', event.refreshToken);
  }

  delete(event, emit) {
    emit(TokenDeleted());
    emit(TokenInitial());
    secureStorage.write('accessToken', null);
    secureStorage.write('refreshToken', null);
  }
}
```

3. Wrap your Home widget with BlocProvider like that

```
return BlocProvider.value(
  value: getIt.get<TokenBloc>(),
  child: const CupertinoApp(
    home: Home(),
  ),
);
```

4. Create a single module for requesting a new refresh token from API, which will use this TokenBloc for updating/deleting tokens. You can access to TokenBloc from RefreshTokenAPI using getIt.

```
getIt.get<TokenBloc>().add(TokenReseted());
```

5. All you have to do is to listen to the TokenBloc changes in your UI and make a redirect.

That’s it. Hope it will help :)

Comment: Please complete your implementation, So it can be understandable